# JSP values printing in server console

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, struts1

My working environment is like, Struts 1.2 framework with jsp pages, ejb2, db2 database and application server is IBM websphere 9 version. I want to see formbean  value in server console. I have written the code for that in jsp file. Example:

```
<%= "Welcome "+ sampleformbean.getType() %>

<% System.out.println("Welcome "+ sampleformbean.getType()) %>

<% out.println("Welcome "+ sampleformbean.getType()) %>
```

But nothing is working. Nothing can be seen in server console. I didn't understand why?. Experts help me. I have to complete work.

NOTE: These codes are inside  html tag.

Comment: why would you even want that? do you get something in your logs? do you get an error?

Comment: Because I want to see the value whether it is coming right or not before I could show that is jsp page.

Comment: correction here: NOTE: These codes are inside html <table> tag instead of NOTE: These codes are inside html tag.

Comment: The only row that will work is the one with System.out

`<% System.out.println("Welcome "+ sampleformbean.getType()) %>`

maybe your webspere server redirects its output to a file. Check for a log file in the server directory

Comment: These messages will be printed to the `SystemOut.log` in `%PROFILE_ROOT%/logs/serverName` folder of the running server, when you will render that page, if the execution will reach that place (you may see for example null pointer earlier if sampleformbean is null).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ttrb_mglogs.html) for details on application logging and trace.